# Extracting part of a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract two characters from the middle of a string. From the strings `['data_EL27.dat', 'data.BV256.dat', 'data_BV257.dat']`, I wish to output `['EL', 'BV', 'BV']`.

Here's what I have using regex, this seems overly clunky for such a simple task, I feel like I'm missing some nicer way of doing this.

```
import re

str = 'data_EL27.dat'
m = re.search(r'(?:data[._])(\w{2})', str)
m.group(1) # 'EL'
```

I realise that in this case I can just take `str[5:7]` but I don't want to rely on the length of the prefix remaining the same.

Comment: Thats pretty tidy by the looks of it although I havent' used python's regex so i'm not sure of it's quirks/shortcuts. I assume you could remove that first capture and use something more like `^\w+[._](\w{2})` as your regex to make it less wordy

Comment: Thanks @rbev. I guess I can get rid of the `^\w+` too and just use `re.search(r'[._](\w{2})', str).group(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be just

```
m=re.search("data.(..)",str)
```

?